# Oracle SQL Update nested within Select

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sql-injection

Is it possible to nest an Update query within a Select query?

Or is there another method of updating rows given that the first word in the query must be 'Select' and ensuring that it is one query (ie. there is no semicolon between queries).

Furthermore, it must be accepted by [JdbcTemplate query](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) (which is why there must be no semicolons).

Thanks for the help.

=====

Update:

I'm trying to inject SQL to update table rows. The table structure doesn't matter but the table must already exist and the rows that it is trying to update must already exist as well.

Example query:

```
UPDATE users
SET username = 'Mike';
```

The only requirement is that the first word in the SQL query must be `SELECT` because that is the only basic sanity check that the server does. Is it possible to do something like this?

=====

Update:

One solution mentioned was to use PL/SQL to call an function that would mutate data. I'm currently looking to see if you can create this function and call it in one or more `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Why in the Holy Hand Grenade would you want a `select` statement to modify data?  This would seem like an excellent way to shoot yourself in the foot.  Can you use PL/SQL?  If so, it's theoretically possible to define a function that uses an autonomous transaction to modify data which gets called from a `select` statement.  It's almost certainly a hideous architectural approach that will make whoever has to support it want to find you and remove your internal organs.  But it can be done.

Comment: Does `query` enforce the first word must be `select` - it doesn't allow CTEs, for example? Why can't you use [`update`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I would rather use a different approach. I'm working on a system where SQL injection is used to allow the client to inject SQL select statements (the server does a sanity check to ensure it starts with 'Select'). Wasn't my idea, but now I need a client to send an update because functionality needs to be added without changing the server.

Comment: Can you use PL/SQL?  So create a function `my_dirty_autonomous_function` and call that in a `select` statement?

Comment: Is it possible to create that function within a `select` statement? This is an incredibly ugly hack and going to do it a different way now, but ultimately very curious to see if this is possible.

Comment: So you want to work around the server's (basic) sanity check for SQL injection to *allow* an update to be injected? How do you validate what is being updated, or that only an update is done? Hopefully you are not proposing to execute arbitrary code, just a predefined update that you can supply variables to. In which case Justin's autonomous approach would work - but still, not a route i'd want to go down without a fight... And the function would have to exist on the DB already, you can't define it within the select, so might still count as a 'server change'.

Comment: Yes, essentially that's what I'm trying to do. Right now, this is just an internal script so we wouldn't be given this client out to customers. We're not going down this route but was wondering if this is possible. The only requirement is that everything necessary for this to be possible must fit in one `select` statement (including declaration of the PL/SQL function which I'm not sure is possible).

Comment: Mike,  how about you begin again, telling us about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking if a vague and theoretical method could possibly be employed ?       And, include things like table structure, data samples, and what the result should LOOK like.    That will give your audience a much better starting point to help you.

Comment: Juan, I've edited the question. Does this help?

Comment: @mikeecb - If you are using Oracle 12.1, you can define the function in the query but it would have to be done in a `WITH` clause that preceeds the `SELECT` (it would still be a `SELECT` statement though).  Otherwise, you'd need to define the function separately.

Comment: @JustinCave the server side checks the first word is `SELECT` to ensure its a `SELECT` statement. It is flawed in the sense it gives false negatives (saying a query starting with a `WITH` clause isn't a `SELECT` statement). Its surprising the amount of defense you have from attackers mutating data by just checking the query starts with a `SELECT`.

Comment: @JustinCave I don't have a 12c db handy, but can the plsql declarations be done like this: `select * from (with function name(param type) return type as begin null; return value; end; select name(param) from dual)` possibly with the `WITH_PLSQL` hint?  Also do you know if subfactored plsql blocks can have the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` clause?

Comment: A semicolon is required for terminating the function declaration in the [enhanced WITH clause introduced in Oracle 12.1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1). So, given that semicolons were not allowed per the OPs requirements, this is not possible in Oracle (unless there's a way to somehow escape these characters in the query *and* declare the function with the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma).